# Overriding method for ArrayLists in Groovy with metaClass

Tags: groovy, arraylist, metaprogramming

I am trying to understand why I cannot modify the behavior of any method using metaprogramming for any instance of ArrayList. This is the code I am using for:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.contains = { Object o -> true }
def list = ['hi','hallo']
assert list instanceof ArrayList
assert list.contains('hola')
```

But it doesn´t work and it throws an exception complaining about the line 4 because list does´t contain 'hola'.

Any clue about it?

If you are asking why do I need to do this, is just because I am writing some unit tests and I need to modify the behaviour of the contains method to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

*I am trying to understand why I cannot modify the behavior of any method using metaprogramming for **any instance of ArrayList***. - Your statement is not in sync with what you are trying to do. :). You are applying metaClass on the Class instead of the instance itself.

`ArrayList` is a Java class and when you try to access metaClass (on the Class itself) and add a new method similar to one that already exists, then it will refer to the already existing `method` in the class.

Instead, try to add `contains` method on the instance itself as:

```
def list = ['hi','hallo']
list.metaClass.contains = { Object o -> true }

assert list instanceof ArrayList
assert list.contains('hola')
```

Or change the name of the method if you want to use the ArrayList Class:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.containssss = { Object o -> true }
def list = ['hi','hallo']
assert list instanceof ArrayList
assert list.containssss('hola')
```

Comment: But the problem is that I have to modify the behaviour of an instance inside a method for which I don't have access directly from the test. I don't understand why I can modify e.g. The method isEmpty for the class String but not for the ArrayList class.

Comment: Tried [replying](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Mocking-method-ArrayList-tp4652902p4652940.html) in the mailing list as well.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why, but this works (just using a typed parameter for the closure):

```
ArrayList.metaClass.contains = { String o -> true } 
def list = ['hi','hallo'] 
assert list instanceof ArrayList 
assert list.contains('hola')​
```